# Conditionally format for "If any other cell in this row contains X"

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm looking for a conditional formatting rule for when the current row (excluding the cell to be formatted) contains a string value. The formatting should be as in the image below. Green font if the rest of the row contains `X`, red font if no `X` is present elsewhere in the row. By 'present' I mean either `X` in a cell on its own or as part of a string such as `X str`, `this X`, etc.

[image: SO29213213 question example]

I've tried with:

```
 =Contains(ROW(),"x")
```

but this does not work, and would have included the cell that shouldn't be included.

Comment: @pnuts updated to describe better now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select all the `Has X` cells and format text colour red ("standard" formatting), then with the same selection Format, Conditional formatting..., **Custom formula is**:

```
=hlookup("X",C2:F2,1,0)="X"
```

Text Colour: green.  Adjust the `C2:F2` range to suit.

Or maybe instead:

```
=match("*"&"X"&"*",C2:F2,0)
```